# how to store values to array using keyboard.next().charAt(0)? in java

Tags: java, arrays, file, redirect, input

This is what I have, but it only works if I have a space in between each character when using file redirection. How do I make it read without any spaces in the .txt file?
    public class MazeAnalyze
    {

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = keyboard.nextInt();// stores the dimensions of the maze
        char[][] mazeValue = new char[n][n];
        String values = keyboard.nextLine();
        char[] mazeValue1 = new char[values.length()];
        for(int j=0; j<values.length(); j++)
            mazeValue1[j] = values.charAt(j);
         printMazeValue(mazeValue);
        }
```

Again, this reads from the file, only if I have spaces, for example [O X O O O ]. How do I make it store values into mazeValue using this [OXOOO]?

Comment: what type is keyboard object?, Anyway are you plan to read only numbers from 0 to 9, otherwise you need to have some delimeter in betweeen.

Comment: only reading O and X from a .txt file

Comment: Of course it will work for one char per space, that's because you call the `.nextInt()` method every time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read chars from input with no delimiter you can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    char[][] mazeValue = new char[n][n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String values = keyboard.nextLine();
        for (int j = 0; j < values.length(); j++) mazeValue[i][j] = values.charAt(j);
    }


}
```

Assuming your input is in format:

```
3
OOO
XXX
ZZZ
```

Comment: when I do that, it gives me an out of bounds error, this is a 2-d array by the way.

Comment: @dextermorgan I edited my answer. You need to make sure you have enough array size to store the input chars. Consider using `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still gives me the out of bounds error. Sorry I'm been so needy, I'm new to java.

Comment: @dextermorgan please post the rest of your code. I can only speculate on how you have initialized your arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should receive the input before the loop starts..

```
String values = keyboard.nextLine();
char[] mazeValue1 = new char[values.length()];
for(int j=0; j<values.length(); j++)
    mazeValue1[j] = values.charAt(j);
```

Comment: this worked but, all of my inputs are reading as 0s. it is not readig O and X

Comment: I tried this code myself and it worked. Something might be wrong with your code.